# libreoffice6.3 error "Failed to open display" & soffice command not found. in cenos7

Tags: centos, operating-system, runtime-error, libreoffice, soffice

i'm using centos7, i have installed libreoffice6.3. it was working file before changing of my computer ip. but after changing ip it is not working. and then i have reinstalled many time. but still it's not working. 
**command & and outputs below**
libreoffice6.3 --version ====  LibreOffice 6.3.4.2 60da17e045e08f1793c57c00ba83cdfce946d0aa
soffice --version ===== -bash: soffice: command not found
libreoffice6.3 ===== Failed to open display

Comment: Have you tried the latest version?

Comment: which is latest version ?

Comment: I'm using latest version only

Comment: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/200826/625-crashes-on-generic-centos-7-install/   
check this

Comment: Hi Raja Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you had openoffice installed? libre and open office share the originally came same source. If you did install one or the other this might cuase the problem. Darshan Dave link also might help you

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just a tip: Every time you need / want to use LibreOffice's functionality without starting up the GUI, add `--headless` the the soffice command. `soffice --help` says

> Starts in "headless mode" which allows using the
> application without GUI. This special mode can be used
> when the application is controlled by external clients
> via the API.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).